# Inserting tag in a HTML using HTMLParser

Tags: java

Is there an easy way to insert a TAG plus tag values in a HTML using [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)? So far what I have used is the NodeVisitor to modify Tag values but not adding a new tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [This](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/util/NodeList.html#prepend%28org.htmlparser.Node%29) and [This](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/util/NodeList.html#add%28org.htmlparser.util.NodeList%29) out, there are two functions that help you to insert new tag. only you need to instantiate your desire Node object then insert it using "second This link" :D

Comment: How do I instantiate a Node/Tag? I tried but I can't instantiate it in my code. Can you site some example?

Comment: Also, the "prepend" function will insert the new Node/Tag as the first element of the root HTML tag right?

Comment: @your 2nd comment. yes. and function : "add" can do this at end and so on.

instantiate is not a hard word :)... just you should be do this work:

Node node = new Node().... and something like this. ok?

Comment: Yah I know that but it gives an error, it says: Cannot instantiate the type Node.

Comment: Node is a Tag. you should new tag. like Div tag and so on

check this link
http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/tags/package-summary.html

and this:

http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/nodes/TagNode.html

Comment: Tag t = new Tag(); // Cannot instantiate also

Comment: no 
Node node = new TagNode();
or
TagNode node = new TagNode();
or
Node node = new DivTag();

Comment: When I try to insert this TagNode via NodeList prepend I get this error: org.htmlparser.nodes.TextNode cannot be cast to org.htmlparser.nodes.TagNode

Comment: And btw, if I insert the TextNode, using "add" it adds to the end of the html document (but outside), also if I use prepend it adds in the start but again outside of the html tag.

Comment: may be you call ADD function for root Node, search for a function with ADD functionality that insert a node INTO the Tag. be success